# Postman API delete functionality issue - delete always the last data

Tags: javascript

```js
// Function to delete the data
app.delete("/api/theTasks/:id", (req, res) => {

    let taskToRemove = Items.find(p => p.id == parseInt(req.params.id));
    let index = Items.indexOf(taskToRemove);
    Items.splice(index, 1);
    res.json(taskToRemove);

});
```

- Please, my application is deleting my last entries instead of the
  desired data.  Please, could you help? unsure, how to pass the
  variable in the URL? I believe I should delete the data based on the
  ID which should be in the URL as a parameter but, It doesn't work for
  me

```js
const URL = "http://localhost:5050/api/theTasks/";
const init = () => {
    getDataa();
    document.querySelector("#newTask").addEventListener("click", addNewTask);
    //addNewTask();
};

/* The method to add a task entered by the user
 */
const addNewTask = () => {

    console.log("Adding a new task...");
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "http://localhost:5050/api/theTasks/";
    let apiKey = "Itcheui2tB58SlUGe8rrP8mskudGsNDT9nfKKG9S";

    let taskDescription = document.querySelector("#task").value;
    let theTask = taskDescription;

    let params = {

        Description: taskDescription
    };
    xhr.open("post", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", apiKey);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {}
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    console.log("Display the data");
    getDataa();
};

/* The method to Get the data from th API
 */
const getDataa = () => {

    console.log("get Data")
    fetch(URL, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "x-api-key": "Itcheui2tB58SlUGe8rrP8mskudGsNDT9nfKKG9S"

            }
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(function(Items) {
            console.log(Items);
            // Loop to access all rows

            let text = '';
            Array.from(Items).forEach(myFunction);
            // display the data to the end user and link it to the index page
            document.getElementById("displayTable").innerHTML = text;

            function myFunction(item) {
                let theTask = item.Description;
                let taskToRemove = Items.id;


                text += ` <button type="button" class="btn" id="task2" onclick="deleteData('${theTask}')"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>   ${theTask}<br>`;
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });


}



 - Here's my code for my own API that I have created using the POSTMAN
   API ... is there an issue with that?

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
/* the method to delete the data
 */
async function deleteData(taskDescription) {


    console.log("deleteing data");

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "http://localhost:5050/api/theTasks/:";

    fetch(url, {
            method: 'DELETE',

            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "x-api-key": "Itcheui2tB58SlUGe8rrP8mskudGsNDT9nfKKG9S",
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({

                'Description': taskDescription,

                'version': 'JSON',
            }),
        })
        .then(res => res.json()).then(console.log);
    console.log(taskDescription);
    getDataa();
}
```

Comment: Doesnt look like you are sending an ID with your url in your fetch request

Comment: Correct, I have tried multiple changes and, it was unsuccessful ... could you help?

Comment: You have to send the ID of the element you are trying to delete to the function. Then include it at the end of the url

Comment: Hmmm, I have tried that ... please, could you shoe it to me in the code?

Comment: updated with the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are already sending the taskDescription to the delete function. Now you just need to add the ID of whatever you are deleting to that same function and append it to the url of the endpoint in the fetch.

```
async function deleteData(taskDescription, elementID) {


    console.log("deleteing data");

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//add the id here
    let url = `http://localhost:5050/api/theTasks/:${elementID}`;

    fetch(url, {
            method: 'DELETE',

            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "x-api-key": "Itcheui2tB58SlUGe8rrP8mskudGsNDT9nfKKG9S",
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({

                'Description': taskDescription,

                'version': 'JSON',
            }),
        })
        .then(res => res.json()).then(console.log);
    console.log(taskDescription);
    getDataa();
}
```

Comment: Hmm - even, with this change ... application still deleting the last task.

Comment: Is there anything else should I change?

Comment: did you get the right ID? I cant really help without being able to see the full code. use console.log when you need to.